# Story of a girl whose parents implant a chip to generate aversion to men

Tags: story-identification

I haven't read this story, but I was reading some reviews of Asimov's "A Perfect Fit" and came across this one line by a reviewer.

> There is a story whose title and author both I have forgotten, which also dealt with the idea of forcing aversion to certain things, only it wasn't used simply for punishment; for instance, one of the main characters was a girl whose parents had had implanted in her an intense aversion to men, to the point where she couldn't even stand close to one, so that she would concentrate on her studies. Either for legal or financial reasons, she couldn't have it removed herself, even though she was a legal adult. I mention this because I think this story dealt with that particular idea a lot better than "A Perfect Fit", though it would be more helpful if I could remember the title.
>
> <sub>[Library Thing, The Winds of Change, stochasticooze's review](http://www.librarything.com/work/313397/reviews/783501)</sub>

I would like to know if anyone knows which story the reviewer is talking about.

Comment: Sounds like something I saw in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkangel_(Black_Mirror)) episode of *Black Mirror*

Comment: Reminds me of [this](https://xkcd.com/573/).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It might be [Dogfight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogfight_(short_story)) by William Gibson.

From wikipedia

> A lonely ex-shoplifter who suffers from a neural block preventing him from returning to his hometown of Washington, D.C., finds a female friend, whose parents have set a neural block on her to protect her virginity – a sort of a mental chastity belt.

In the story the friend describes her block like this.

> She laughed. And then, because he sensed the time was right, he reached
> out to take her hand.
>
> "Don't  you  touch  me,  motherfuck, don't  you  ever  touch me!" Nance
> screamed,  and her head slammed against  the wall as she recoiled, white and
> shaking with terror.
>
> "Okay!" He threw up his hands. "Okay! I'm nowhere near you. Okay?"
>
> She cowered from  him. Her eyes were round  and unblinking; tears built
> up at the corners, rolled down ashen cheeks. Finally,  she  shook  her head.
>
> "Hey. Deke. Sorry. I should've told you."
>
> "Told me what?" But he had a creepy feeling.  already knew. The way she
> clutched her head. The weakly  spasmodic  way her  hands opened  and closed.
> "You got a brainlock, too."
>
> "Yeah." She closed her eyes.  "It's a chastity lock. My asshole parents
> paid  for it. So I  can't stand  to have anybody touch me or even stand  too
> close." Eyes opened in blind hate. "I didn't even do anything. Not a fucking
> thing. But  they've both got  jobs and  they're so  horny for  me  to have a
> career that they can't  piss straight. They're afraid I'd neglect my studies
> if  I got, you know, involved in sex and stuff.  The day the brainlock comes
> off I am going to fuck the vilest, greasiest, hairiest . .

Comment: It's the one that immediately sprang to mind for me, too.

Comment: Mine as well.  What a horrible little story it was, too.  No insult to Gibson - it's just that the twitchy, dirty feeling that the ending left me with has never entirely gone away.  If anything, that's praise, of a sort.

Comment: @BenBarden, then I don't think I'd want to read it. I already have too many things stuck in my head.

Comment: @BenBarden how long ago did you read it?

Comment: @BenBarden Totally agree, and of course that was the point. The protagonist wins the game, but loses everything that really matters.

Comment: This may be it, but Wikipedia's brilliance aside, the anti-sex chip is a minor thing. Dogfight is about something completely different (a dogfight, it turns out) and she wasn't even the main character. But again, maybe the reviewer through Gibson's throwaway was better than Asimov's entire story.

Comment: @OwenReynolds She certainly was *a* main character, just not the protagonist.  Is Inigo Montoya not a main character in *The Princess Bride*, just because Westley is the one who gets the girl? :)  And whilst the titular dogfight is what it leads up to, what the story is really about is how far someone will do for what they're obsessed with.  As for your last point, it wasn't a "throwaway" - the collection it was in, *Burning Chrome*, is pretty much required reading for anyone slightly interested in sci-fi.

Comment: @Graham Be that as it may, the story mentions the anti-sex chip once and doesn't explore it. The reviewer in the Q is mis-remembering that it's a story "which also dealt with the idea of forcing aversion".

Comment: @OwenReynolds That's not the case though. It's key to the guy's relationship with her, knowing her can't touch her. There's a scene where she dances around saying "I'm the virgin goddess" which relates to it. And it's the way the guy forces her to give him the drug which lets him win the game. We also know about a similar chip he has, where he flips out if he sees two red lights, and that's intimately described. The chip isn't the point of the story, but it's a very key and very well covered part of the plot.